# How can this account address selled more erc20 token then it received?

Tags: transactions, erc-20, etherscan, balances, api

[image: etherscan transaction]

I'm using the Alchemy API to retrieve all transactions for a specific address. When I run the API for this address on this particular token, I only receive two transactions. The first transaction shows a purchase, and the second transaction shows a sale. Etherscan also displays the same two transactions that I'm getting from Alchemy's API.

How is it possible that this address is selling 53,523.2202 tokens when it has only received 47,500 tokens, and there are no other ERC-20 token transfers in this account?

Etherscan LInk:

https://etherscan.io/advanced-filter?fadd=0xaf2358e98683265cbd3a48509123d390ddf54534&tadd=0xaf2358e98683265cbd3a48509123d390ddf54534&txntype=2&tkn=0x2660fc5995dc41b07c5094629b673697b8e1cac0

Thank you

Comment: Can you add the address or link to etherscan in your question body?

Comment: Of course, edited.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The token contract has a lot of functionalities, that are not in any ERC20 token. For example, if you checked the contract you will find that the `_transfer` function has a different logic than just sending the token holding amount.

```php
function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private {
    require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
    require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
    require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
    if (_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferFromExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferToExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else if (!_isExcluded[sender] && !_isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else if (_isExcluded[sender] && _isExcluded[recipient]) {
        _transferBothExcluded(sender, recipient, amount);
    } else {
        _transferStandard(sender, recipient, amount);
    }
}
```

The token has a lot of functionality that is hard to understand, as there are no comments in the code, but it's not a typical transfer function.

So there may be a logic for taking fees to the deployer, or minting functionality that increases holders' tokens.

Answer (score 0):

It's a reflection mechanic like the one popularised by Safemoon, where a fee gets distributed among holders based on their token balance.
Balances can be adjusted without seeing a transfer event in a block  explorer.

RF1 is a fork of RFI "Reflect Finance", with a 5% "reflect redistribution fee".

So the account bought, then when others bought their balance increased as a result of fees.

Sources: https://reflect.finance/ | https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=5313368.0

Comment: Thankyou so much

Comment: You're welcome.